# When the sample sizes of two datasets are greatly different, is the result of non-parametric testing still reliable?

Tags: nonparametric, sample

I want to investigate whether there is a significant difference in the centrality of eigenvectors between two groups. The sample sizes of the two groups are over 9000 and 300, respectively, with a large difference. I used the Mann-Whitney U non-parametric test, and I want to know whether the result of the non-parametric test is reliable.

Comment: In what sense do you mean "reliable"? Usually the things people would focus on are accuracy of chosen significance level ($\alpha$) and/or good power. Do you mean one of those, or do you mean something else?

Comment: A representative sample of 300 is worth more than a less representative sample of 9000.